# Python Flask unit test with pytest: error if more than one test is run and the app uses Firebase

Tags: python, firebase, flask, pytest

I have this code for creating my pytest fixtures. I got this code from [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/testing/):

```py
import pytest
from my_project import create_app

@pytest.fixture()
def app():
    app = create_app()
    app.config.update({
        "TESTING": True,
    })

    # other setup can go here

    yield app

    # clean up / reset resources here


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture()
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

In my create app function, I initialize a firebase app. When I run pytest, when it gets to the second test, I get a ValueError. Specifically:

> ValueError: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you
> called initialize_app() more than once without providing an app name
> as the  second argument. In most cases you only need to call
> initialize_app() once.  But if you do want to initialize multiple
> apps, pass a second argument to  initialize_app() to give each app a
> unique name.

This is the part in the `create_app` function where the firebase app is initialized:

```py
    # Initialize Firebase and Firestore connections
    firebase_credentials = credentials.Certificate(app.config['FIREBASE_KEY_PATH'])
    firebase_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(firebase_credentials)
    db = firestore.client()
```

How do I solve this? I can see the fixture is functioning as a generator because of yield, but I don't understand if a new app is being created for each test while the previous app still is up. Not sure really, anyway that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: A fixture by default has a `function` scope, which means the fixture is run once -- and yields a new value -- for every test. Read more about scope [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#scope-sharing-fixtures-across-classes-modules-packages-or-session).

Comment: Should the initialization of a firebase app even be a part of the create_app function in the Flask application factory pattern? Or should that be separate somehow?
One of the things i don't understand is that in generators that yield, the previous value is supposed to be discarded when the new one is made, meaning I'm expecting the first app instance to be discarded by the time we are at the second test, yet the error complains that an app already exists, as if the first one wasn't actually discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def app():

    # The config options are passed during creating of the app instead of configuring them afterwards because they are needed during view function decoration time
    config = {
        "TESTING": True,
        "DEVELOPER_IP_LIST": ['127.0.0.1'],
        "DEVELOPER_PASS": 'mockpassword',
        "WTF_CSRF_ENABLED": False,
    }
    app = create_app(config=config)

    # other setup can go here

    yield app

    # clean up / reset resources here
    firebase_app = firebase_admin.get_app()
    firebase_admin.delete_app(firebase_app)
```

`get_app()` gets the firebase app instance that was initialized during setup. `delete_app()` then deletes it during teardown. I have no idea why it had to be like this, i assumed the whole flask app, including the firebase app, would automatically get deleted because of `yield`.

Comment: You have no guarantee that Python performs any cleanup just because a variable goes out of scope. Performing explicit cleanup is the correct solution.